# Alinhamento vertical de icones

Tags: css

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

uma `div` com `width: 228px` e `height: 228px`.

Classe: `icons` um elemento `<a>` com com tamanho da imagem (ícone).

O problema é que tenho alguns casos que tem 3 ícones(1 linha) e outros com mais de 3 ícones, formando mais do que uma linha. Ou seja, o meu alinhamento não fica exatamente no centro quando utilizo mais de 3 ícones(2 linhas).

Link com o problema:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k31pces7/)

Observe que o a primeira linha de ícones esta exatamente no centro(verticalmente), mas não esta levando em consideração a segunda linha de ícones.

**Resolvido!**

Retirei o código do seletor #icon:

```
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Criei uma nova div chamada alinha_icons:

```
<div id="icons">
   <div id="alinha_icons">
       <a class="icon" target="_blank" href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>
       <a class="icon" target="_blank" href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>
       <a class="icon" target="_blank" href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>
       <a class="icon" target="_blank" href="#"><img src="img.png"></a>
    </div>
</div>

#alinha_icons{
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%);
position: relative;
display: block;}
```

Assim fazendo com que a `div` alinha_icons ficasse com o tamanho de todos os ícones e alinhado em relação ao tamanho da `div` .icons.

OBS: este foi um código provisorio pois não queria mudar meu código, mas pode ser resolvido de outras formas, se alguém tiver outras soluções peço para que postem.

Comment: Oi Gabriel. Por favor poste sua solução como resposta na área mais abaixo, e marque ela como a resposta aceita. Assim fica mais organizado. Recomendo uma olhada no nosso [tour], aqui funciona diferente dos fóruns tradicionais. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isto é um comportamento normal, a largura ocupada por todos os `<a>` é maior que a da sua div `#icons`. Mesmo que você use a propriedade `white-space:nowrap` (em `#icons`) o conteúdo interno ultrapassará o limite:

[image: img]

Nesse caso você tem duas opções: Diminuir o tamanho ocupado pelos elementos filhos ou aumentar a largura do elemento pai.

#### Alternativa

Quando não se tem uma quantidade fixa de elementos internos, a melhor solução pode ser utilizar a propriedade `flexbox`.

- [Navegadores que suportam](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)
- [Flexbox na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/CSS/Usando_caixas_flexiveis_css)
- [Um guia bem completo no CSS-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

#### Exemplo:

```css
* {-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing: border-box;}

/* Só isso...
   Não precisei definir nada nos elementos filhos */
.documents {
    display: -webkit-flex;
     display: -ms-flexbox;  
        display: -moz-box;
            display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

/* Só para melhorar a visualização, as regras abaixo não tem relevância */
.documents {background: #27ae60;height:60px;width: 300px}
.documents span {color: #fff;margin: 12.5px 1px 0 1px;font-size: 2em}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'/>

<p>Com um único elemento</p>
<div class='documents'>
    <span class='fa fa fa-file-word-o'></span>
</div>

<p>Com mais de um...</p>
<div class='documents'>
    <span class='fa fa fa-file-word-o'></span>
    <span class='fa fa fa-file-word-o'></span>
    <span class='fa fa fa-file-word-o'></span>
    <span class='fa fa fa-file-word-o'></span>
</div>

<p>Com mais ainda...</p>
<div class='documents'>
    <span class='fa fa fa-file-word-o'></span>
    <span class='fa fa fa-file-word-o'></span>
    <span class='fa fa fa-file-word-o'></span>
    <span class='fa fa fa-file-word-o'></span>
    <span class='fa fa fa-file-word-o'></span>
    <span class='fa fa fa-file-word-o'></span>
    <span class='fa fa fa-file-word-o'></span>
    <span class='fa fa fa-file-word-o'></span>
    <span class='fa fa fa-file-word-o'></span>
</div>
```